# Make table overflow scroll and prevent HTML table from forcing wrapper to exceed container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this has been driving me mad, I have been trying to make the table content clipped
by hiding the parent wrapper's overflow, and enable `overflow-x scroll` on the table wrapper so that the table content is horizontally scrollable.

I have added the code to the codesandbox, and you can see the table wrapper (with the green background) is exceeding the containers.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tesla-0o1mte

Does anyone know how `.scrollable-table` can be the same width as it's parent (`#panel`) and enable horizontal scrolling for the table?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
I feel this is a little closer. Using flex-grow to make the wrapping panel take up the full width. If I set the table to `display none` the parent takes up the correct amount of space, so now purely the table breaking the layout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-proskuriakova-bi375b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all you need to do is to add `flex: 1` and a specific width to the `.right` class:

```
.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Forked sandbox:

[image: Edit hungry-thunder-5obv0k]

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much, can I ask, why is the width 1px?

Comment: @LeMoi not an expert here, but if width is not set, it will have `width: auto` and it will follow its child's width, the specified width can be any values you want, but in this case it will be handled by `flex: 1` so that it won't really be `1px`

Comment: @LeMoi haha, no worries, I didn't even downvote, glad could help